# Wedge product of three non-distinct real differential $1$-forms

Tags: differential-forms, exterior-algebra

When talking about the wedge (exterior) product with regard to real differential $k$-forms, I know that if $\alpha$ is a $k_1$-form and $\beta$ is a $k_2$-form, then their wedge product is a $(k_{1}+k_{2})$-form such that $$\alpha \wedge \beta = (-1)^{k_{1}k_{2}}\beta \wedge \alpha\text{.}$$ In particular, if $k =k_1 = k_2= 1$ and $\alpha = \beta$, then $$\alpha \wedge \alpha =0\text {.} $$ This says that the wedge product of a $1$-form $\alpha$ with itself is $0$. But then what would be the wedge product of three such $1$-forms $\alpha$, i.e. $\alpha \wedge \alpha \wedge \alpha$? Would it also be $0$?

I'm certainly aware that the wedge product is associative. So clearly $$\begin{align*}
(\alpha \wedge \alpha) \wedge \alpha &= \alpha \wedge (\alpha \wedge \alpha) \\
0 \wedge \alpha &= \alpha \wedge 0
\end{align*} \text {,}$$ where $\alpha$ is a $1$-form. Now what is $0 \wedge \alpha$? Is $0$ a $0$-form?

Comment: prove and use $\varepsilon^k\wedge 0=0$ and use $\alpha=a_s\varepsilon^s$ in a distribution of $\wedge0$

Comment: What will I conclude from that? Will it be that the wedge product with $0$ is always $0$?

Comment: . . . a fortiori

Comment: The symbol $0$ is typically used indiscriminately to denote the zero elements of many different vector spaces. In the equations $\alpha\wedge\alpha=0$ and $0\wedge \alpha = \alpha \wedge 0$, the symbol $0$ represents the zero two-form. But in $0\wedge\alpha = 0$, it's representing a two-form on the left and a three-form on the right. Admittedly, this is a little inconsistent; but if you start trying to put subscripts or other decorations on every occurrence of $0$ to indicate which vector space (or ring, or abelian group, or whatever) it's the zero of, you'll soon see why we do it this way.